# Spring AbstractPdfView - change the response so it has a file name rather than the request path

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, request-mapping

I have a controller that returns a view that overrides `AbstractPdfView`.  Works great except for the fact when the user goes to save the PDF form the browser it tries to save a the request path (seems reasonable but not what I want).

The controller code is:

```
public class MealPlanPDFController {

    private MealPlannerDao mealPlannerDao;
    private UserDao userDao;
    //protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setMealPlanDao(MealPlannerDao mealPlannerDao) {
        this.mealPlannerDao = mealPlannerDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Transactional
    protected ModelAndView handleRequest(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(request.getContextPath());
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView(new MealPlanPDFView());
        MealPlan mealPlan = mealPlannerDao.getMealPlan(id, true);
        ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        Resource res = new ServletContextResource(servletContext,"/images/logo.png");

        URL url = res.getURL();
        modelView.addObject("mealPlan",mealPlan);
        modelView.addObject("imageURL",url);
        System.out.println(url.getPath());
        return modelView;
    }
}
```

So the request path is:

`api/mealplanpdf/1`   where 1 is the id for the MealPlan.

On the response I woulf like it to be `mealplan_1.pdf`.

Makes sense?  Any idea how I would do that?

Thanks

Comment: in case someone else runs into this just needed the following...`response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");`